# Filter a list based on multiple criteria and multiple values (unknown number of values)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class `User`:

```
public class User{
    // some properties
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PerfLoc { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    // constructor would follow ..
}
```

Than I have a class `PerfLoc`:

```
public class PerfLoc{
    // some properties
    public string Number { get; set; }
    // constructor would follow ..
}
```

I have a list of users `List<User> myUsers` and a list `List<PerfLoc> myPerfLoc`. Now I want to find all users of `myUsers` which have a certain `PerfLoc`. So I have multiple values in `myUsers` and multiple values in `myPerfLoc`. The exercise now is to make a match. I thought about some sort of pseudeo code like this:

```
List<User> filteredUser = new List<User> ();
foreach(PerfLoc currentPerfLoc in myPerfLoc){
    filteredUser += myUsers.Any(u => u.PerfLoc == currentPerfLoc.Number);
}
filteredUser = filterUser.Any(u => u.Active = true);
filteredUser.Sort();
```

Here I'd have sorted after `PerfLoc` and `Active` (= multiple criteria) and also after multiple values (list of `PerfLoc.Number`). I saw some *from, where, select* LINQ expressions and thought that my approach above could be expressed in a shorter way. How would you express that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a [join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb311040.aspx) statement in LINQ. Similar to in SQL you put the two lists together and match them on a property or expression. You can also sort using [orderby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx).

The following is a basic check for Active Users matching a list of PerfLocs:

```
var filteredUser = from u in myUsers
                join p in myPerfLocs on u.PerfLoc equals p.Number.ToString()
                where u.Active == true
                orderby u // or u.Name if you need to
                select u;
```

As you are conditionally checking Active state and against myPerfLocs, there may be a way to do it in a single clause but it would look messy, so I would keep it as separate checks anyway - shorter is not always cleaner. You can create a result IEnumerable and then filter that as necessary:

```
bool checkActive = true;

// set up result list - variable needs to be IEnumerable<User>, not List<User>
var filteredUser = myUsers.AsEnumerable();

// add Active check if necessary
if (checkActive)
{
    filteredUser = filteredUser.Where(u => u.Active);
}

// check against PerfLoc list if necessary
if (myPerfLocs.Any())
{
    filteredUser = from u in filteredUser
                    join p in myPerfLocs on u.PerfLoc equals p.Number.ToString()
                    select u;
}

filteredUser = filteredUser.OrderBy(u => u); // or (u => u.Name) etc if you want
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/hrnNmJ for a working sample.

Comment: A slightly different way of writing the same thing can be explored at - "Using Multiple from Clauses to Perform Joins"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx But in general, yes, joins it is...

Comment: Do I nee the second `where u.Active == true` because the check has been made before? Otherwise I would also need to take a `false` into account.

Comment: I tried your approach without the `where` clause and the result set is empty. If I use `filteredUser` as Enumerable can I access `u.PerfLoc` then? The autocomplete functions doesn't show me anything after the dot (.) but it compiles and runs (without results).

Comment: Sorry yes I have removed the second `where Active`. You should get full intellisense inside the linq because VS know that `u` is of type `User`. I've added a link to a .NETFiddle to show it in action.

Comment: I see some differences in your .NETFiddle: I'm using `List` and you are using arrays. The class `User` is derived from `IComparable` which is not the case in my application. Also you've implemented a `CompareTo` method in your `User` class. Could that be the reason that it shows me an empty list in my adapted application? Do I need these? I'm using Xamarin Studio for my application but I think that should be no difference. Thanks for your great support!

Comment: Using arrays or lists shouldn't make any difference - they are both Enumerable. As you are doing filteredUser.Sort() at the end, I assumed User must implement IComparable, or you get a runtime error. Changing to lists and comparing on Name works just as well: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RgxHYW

Comment: Hmmm, your example works wonderful. I can't see any error in my application. After the join command intellisense doesn't show me something. If I try to debug I get "Unknown identifier p". Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Join`. But note that in the code you provided `User.PerfLoc` is `int` and `PerfLoc.Number` is `string`. If this is really the case then you have to add a conversion to the code below.

```
var filteredUser = myUsers.Where(u => u.Active)
                          .Join(myPerfLoc, (u) => u.PerfLoc, 
                                           (p) => p.Number, 
                                           (u, p) => u);
```

Comment: You're right I need a cast. What is if I don't need *Active* or the *PerfLoc*? So there can be one filter criteria but also multiple? Should I use a different `if` statement?

Comment: do you mean you want to check against 0 or more PerfLocs and 0 or more possible values of Active? So they may possibly want active _and_ inactive users back and optionally check against a list of PerfLocs?

Comment: I check if `myPerfLoc` is empty. Than I check if `Active` is set. In the first case `myPerfLoc` can have multiple items and the `Active` option is set. So I filter after both filter criteria. In the second case `myPerfLoc` is empty and I don't need to check it, but I have to check for `Active`. In the latter case `Active` is empty but I have a `myPerfLoc` list which should be used for filtering.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain the syntax of your query in more detail?

Comment: I found this here which helps to understand the syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534644%28v=vs.100%29.aspx